# put(key, value) in Multi-level hashMap in java

Tags: java, hashmap

The program is as below:

```
Hash<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> data = new Hash<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>();

HashMap<String, String> person = new HashMap<String, String>();
        person.put("Name", json.getString("Name"));
        person.put("Contact", json.getString("Contact"));
        person.put("Email", json.getString("Email"));
        person.put("Rent Start", json.getString("Rent Start"));
        person.put("Rent End", json.getString("Rent End"));

String period = json.getString("Rent Start").substring(0, 7) + " To " + json.getString("Rent End").substring(0, 7);

data.get(roomType).put(period, person);
```

Assume "data" is not empty in each level.
Problem occurs in the following step.

```
data.get(roomType).put(period, person);
```

When I do so, all values in the hashmap that in the second level become the person hashmap.

> For example, in "roomtype1", there are 2 period, "2015-07 To 2016-07"
>   and "2015-07 To 2017-07".

When I run this code:

```
data.get(roomtype1).put("2015-07 To 2016-07", person);
```

the hashmap got by

`data.get(roomtype1).get("2015-07 To 2017-07");`

also becomes `person`.

May I know why?

(p.s. The original hashmap has 5 levels. I reduced it for this post because it will be easier to be understood)

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where you add values to the hashMap `data`?

Comment: Can you post the content inside your `data` hashmap.

Comment: I have edited my post. The data is in Chinese. I am afraid that you may not understand. Basically, I firstly put some data into the hashmap person, and then add it into the selected second level hashmap.

Would using Chinese in java be a possible reason for this problem?

Comment: What you mean by "all values in the hashmap that in the second level become the addition hashmap"?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I mean the person hashmap.

HashMap has Key and Value. All values mean the values of the second level hashmap.

Comment: 5 lvl hashmap? 0_0. have u considered using classes, or something like JSON Array-Object instead?

Comment: I think its better to create an Object with appropriate overrides and use it with the highlevel hashmap

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON but actually I am building an apps that have 5 related views. I get data from database and store the data by JSON Array-Object. I thought that hashmap is more convenient since I  have a clearer concept in hashmap than that of JSON Array-Object.

Comment: Alright, I will try to use object instead of multilevel map. Thanks all .

Answer (score 0):

Java objects are reference type.

`data.get(key1)` will get the hashmap object in the second level. with that object you are adding one more object into it.

Comment: Yes, I want to add one more element in that hashmap but the problematic code not only changed the selected second level's hashamp but also changed other hashmap with different keys in the second level.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do so, all values in the hashmap that in the second level
>   become the addition hashmap.

What does `data.get(roomType)` ? Is it doing something like:

```
public V get(K key) {
  V actual = super.get(key);
  if (null == actual) {
    actual = getANewV();
    super.put(key, actual);
  }
  return actual;
}
```

And are you sure that the `getANewV()` always returns a new instance and not the same (which would explains *all values in the hashmap that in the second level become the addition hashmap*).

And your need already exists in the matter of Multimap (see Guava). You should probably see if that work for you. 
Beside, I'd personally use object rather than multiple layer of maps.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use object instead. It seems that using hashmap in this case is really silly.....